# OS X app WebView not loading through code

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, browser

I have spent about a whole day of grief trying to solve this question, and this is my last resort. I have a web view in my OS X app. I made a web browser and it is working great with navigation arrows and all, but when I try to make a home page (google) It does not load on the WebView (called webber in the code). I made sure all the outlets are connected. here is my code for AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{
    NSWindow *window;
    NSTextField *urlBox;
    IBOutlet WebView *webber;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *googleSearchField;
}

-(IBAction)search;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

and here is the code for AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)windowController{
    NSLog(@"Nib loaded");
    NSString *urlText = @"http://www.google.com";
    [[webber mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
}

-(IBAction)search
{
    NSString *searchString = [googleSearchField stringValue];
    NSString *searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@", searchString];
[[webber mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: searchURL]]];
}

@end
```

I would very much appreciate ***ANY*** form of help and I am very desperate. Please remember that I am only in 6th grade, and a step by step guide or just plain code is what I am looking for. Thank you for your time! download the Xcode project here: http://www.cadenfarley.com/cobra/Download.html Scroll down until you see "Xcode project here"

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, and is absolutely not related with your problem...

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: @jediob1, Don't use the tag Xcode, people get mad when you do that. Anyways, check my latest comment below. I have another idea.

Comment: Please only use the Xcode tag if you have issues with the IDE. If you've got issues with Objective-C, then Xcode has nothing to do with it...

Comment: Oh, ok :) I will change it (If i can, that is)

Comment: @jediob1, I believe Macmade already did.

Answer (score 1):

Your `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` method is never called because you don't have an `NSWindowController` anywhere. Rename that method to `- (void)awakeFromNib` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like this case is closed! And thanks, Josiah too!

Comment: @Josiah Actually, it only works sometimes!(rarley) I open it, it works, i close it, and open it again, it stops working! :(

Comment: @jediob1, try `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` instead of -(void)awakeFromNib. I use applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: Also, I have a basic web browser (Open Source), that you can download. It may help you figure out what you want to do. https://sites.google.com/site/infiniteopensyntax/basic-web-browser